# Can't pass a Variant Array to a Subroutine via .OnAction

Tags: excel, vba

This works just fine, when you click the menu item the subroutine AddEmployeeToTask is called with no error messages:

```
Sub AssignTaskToEmployeeFromEmployeeList(ClickedCell As Range, ListOfEmployees() As Variant)
    With CommandBars.Add(Name:="Menu", Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Plock"
            .OnAction = "=AddEmployeeToTask(1, 9, 5, """ & ClickedCellAddress & """, """ & "Plock" & """)"
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub AddEmployeeToTask(TaskColumn As Integer, BoardOffset As Integer, RowsInTask As Integer, ClickedCellAddress As String, Task As String)
End Sub
```

This doesn't, you get Error 400:

```
Sub AssignTaskToEmployeeFromEmployeeList(ClickedCell As Range, ListOfEmployees() As Variant)
    With CommandBars.Add(Name:="Menu", Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Plock"
            .OnAction = "=AddEmployeeToTask(ListOfEmployees, 1, 9, 5, """ & ClickedCellAddress & """, """ & "Plock" & """)"
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub AddEmployeeToTask(ListOfEmployess() As Variant, TaskColumn As Integer, BoardOffset As Integer, RowsInTask As Integer, ClickedCellAddress As String, Task As String)
End Sub
```

The difference is that in the last example I've added a variant array as the first parameter of the subroutine. `ListOfEmployees` If I remove it, the code works just fine.

Is there a special syntax to use when adding arrays as parameters to .OnAction?